# NSIS Installer Silent run app -- Electron

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

We have a electron app that uses a custom nsis script for installer. While that works as it should, for some reason, I'm not able to trigger the app to auto start if its installing in Silent mode.

If the app is installed normally (e.g: double click on `.exe`, it starts automatically), however if used from command line something like:

`"installer.exe" /S`

It doesn't seem to start automatically.

Installer script so far used (`installer.nsh`):

```
!macro preInit
   SetRegView 64 ... some reg things -- OK
   SetRegView 32 ... some reg things -- OK
!macroend

!macro customInit
; SHUT DOWN APP IF CURRENTLY RUNNING
${GetProcessInfo} 0 $0 $1 $2 $3 $4
    ${if} $3 != "${APP_EXECUTABLE_FILENAME}"
    ${nsProcess::FindProcess} "${APP_EXECUTABLE_FILENAME}" $R0
    ${If} $R0 == 0
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "App currently running - going to shutdown to install new version"
      ${nsProcess::CloseProcess} "${APP_EXECUTABLE_FILENAME}" $R0
      Sleep 5000
      ${nsProcess::KillProcess} "${APP_EXECUTABLE_FILENAME}" $R0
      Sleep 3000
   ${EndIf}
   ${nsProcess::Unload}
${endIf}

; Workaround for installer handing when the app directory is removed manually
${ifNot} ${FileExists} "$INSTDIR"
  DeleteRegKey HKCU ...other reg thing
${EndIf}

!macroend

 ---the culprit---
 Function .onInstSuccess
 IfSilent +2 0  
   Exec '"$INSTDIR\app.exe"'
 FunctionEnd
```

I have tried a different variation with:

```
Function .onInstSuccess
    IfSilent +2 0
    Exec '"Absolute\Path\To\app.exe"'
FunctionEnd
```

Alternatively, setting something like: `SetSilent normal` in that `customInit` macro, triggers the behaviour like when double clicking on the `.exe`, where the installer screen appears.

Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since the app is built with electron along-side electron builder, even if custom .nsh file is provided, the app should still not start if installed in manual mode, as pointed out [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1545).

After a bit of research, that feature can be enabled back, if provided in the command line params as such ([pointed out here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/pull/1712/commits/7dc19352581985f11d470f32daed34ac5bc5ab18))

`myAppInstaller.exe /S --force-run`

Answer (score 1):

`IfSilent +2 0` skips the `Exec` if the installer is silent! Just remove that line.

Silent installers don't usually start the app so ideally you should not change anything.

Comment: I would need to determine if the installer runs in silent mode, as if it runs with double click / regular mode, it starts automatically. (in this case silent install is needed as its a requirement to run as such, part of deployment)

Comment: removed the line, still no go, app not starting up after install

Comment: What happens if you change Exec to MessageBox?

Comment: nothing pops up, like ignoring anything in that hook entirely, if in silent mode